# testing react component with 'relay-test-utils'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graphql, relay, relaymodern

I am created some components with React  with Relay/NextJs, I read the documentation for applied tests: https://relay.dev/docs/en/testing-relay-components, I have been tried to create the test for Fragment Container Tests, with the Mock Payload Generator and @relay_test_operation Directive:

```
import SearchPageContainer from '../components/SearchPageContainer'
import ReactTestRenderer from 'react-test-renderer'
import { QueryRenderer, graphql } from 'react-relay'
import {
  createMockEnvironment,
  MockPayloadGenerator,
  generateAndCompile
} from 'relay-test-utils'

describe('SearchPageContainer', () => {
  let testComponent
  let environment

  beforeEach(() => {
    environment = createMockEnvironment()
    const TestRenderer = () => (
      <QueryRenderer
        environment={environment}
        query={graphql`
        query TestQuery @relay_test_operation {
          view: node(id: "test-id") {
            ...MyConnectionFragment
          }
        }
      `}
        variables={{}}
        render={({ error, props }) => {
          if (props) {
            return <SearchPageContainer view={props} />
          } else if (error) {
            return error.message
          }
          return 'Loading...'
        }}
      />
    )
    ReactTestRenderer.act(() => {
      testComponent = ReactTestRenderer.create(<TestRenderer />)
    })
  })
  it('should have pending operations in the queue', () => {
    expect(environment.mock.getAllOperations().length).toEqual(1)
  })
  it('should resolve query', () => {
    environment.mock.resolveMostRecentOperation(operation =>
      MockPayloadGenerator.generate(operation)
    )
    expect(testComponent).toMatchSnapshot()
  })
})
```

I have this error:  Relay Transform Error: You supplied a field named `node` on type `Query`, but no such field exists on that type.

My configuration in the .babelrc is this:

```
{
    "presets": [
      "next/babel",
    ],
    "plugins": [
      ["relay", {"compat": true, "schema": "schema/schema.json"}],
    ]
}
```

I don't know if I need some extra configuration for this @relay_test_operation directive works,

appreciate your help

Comment: Can you show example of your schema? Is there a `node` query on your root query?

Comment: Hi, thank you for your comment, I tried to delete the node, But relay don't recognized the directive @relay_test_operation, I don't know if I need some extra configuration

Comment: query TestQuery @relay_test_operation {
          ...MyConnectionFragment
 }

Comment: I'm experiencing the same is there someone found any solution for this?

Comment: In my case this was caused because of outdated relay version, suggest to upgrade to the latest Relay version.

Answer (score 0):

There are two main modules that you will enjoy using in your tests:

- createMockEnvironment
- mockPayloadGenerator

The `createMockEnvironment` nothing more than an implementation the Relay Environment Interface and it also has an additional mock layer, with methods that allow resolving/reject and control of operations (queries/mutations/subscriptions). It is a special version of Relay Environment with additional API methods for controlling the resolving and rejection operations. Therefore the first thing we should do is tell jest that we don't want the default environment but our environment provided by relay-test-utils.

The `mockPayloadGenerator` is to improve the process of creating and maintaining the mock data for tested components it can generate dummy data for the selection that you have in your operation.

Check this post with examples: [How to test your relay components with relay-test-utils and react-testing-library](https://dev.to/augustocalaca/how-to-test-your-relay-components-with-relay-test-utils-and-react-testing-library-5bk3)